# Error with converting gulp scripts from V3 to V4

Tags: javascript, npm, sass, gulp, gulp-4

I am updating to gulp4 from 3.9.1 on an old project. Due to the upgrade I've had to rewrite the tasks as per the documentation. I've switched to name functions and I am using gulp.series but I am getting errors such as:

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: mobile_styles

Below is my gulp file. It consists mostly of watch scripts for two languages on desktop and mobile

```
var fontName = "project-icons",
    gulp = require("gulp"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass"),
    sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps"),
    iconfont = require("gulp-iconfont"),
    iconfontCss = require("gulp-iconfont-css");

var sassOptions = {
    errLogToConsole: true,
    outputStyle: "expanded"
};

function iconfont(done) {
    gulp.src(["./icons/*.svg"])
        .pipe(
            iconfontCss({
                fontName: fontName,
                path: "sass",
                targetPath: "../sass/static/icons/_icons.sass",
                fontPath: "./fonts/",
                cssClass: "icon"
            })
        )
        .pipe(
            iconfont({
                formats: ["ttf", "eot", "woff", "woff2", "svg"],
                fontName: fontName,
                normalize: true,
                fixedWidth: true,
                centerHorizontally: true
            })
        )
        .on("glyphs", function(glyphs, options) {})
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./fonts/"));
    done();
}

function desktop_styles() {
    return gulp
        .src("./sass/_en/style.sass")
        .pipe(
            sourcemaps.init({
                loadMaps: true,
                identityMap: true,
                sourceRoot: "../css/"
            })
        )
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./css/"));
}

function desktop_styles_rtl() {
    return gulp
        .src("./sass/_ar/style.sass")
        .pipe(
            sourcemaps.init({
                loadMaps: true,
                identityMap: true,
                sourceRoot: "../css/"
            })
        )
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./css/lang/rtl"));
}

function mobile_styles() {
    return gulp
        .src("./sass/en/mobile/style.sass")
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./css/m"));
}

function mobile_styles_rtl() {
    return gulp
        .src("./sass/rtl/m/style.sass")
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./css/lang/rtl/m"));
}

gulp.task(
    "watch:all",
    gulp.series(
        "mobile_styles",
        "mobile_styles_rtl",
        "desktop_styles",
        "desktop_styles_rtl",
        function() {
            gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["mobile_styles"]);
            gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["mobile_styles_rtl"]);
            gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["desktop_styles"]);
            gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["desktop_styles_rtl"]);
        }
    )
);

gulp.task(
    "watch:AllDesktop",
    gulp.series("desktop_styles", "desktop_styles_rtl", function() {
        gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["desktop_styles"]);
        gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["desktop_styles_rtl"]);
    })
);

gulp.task(
    "watch:desktop_styles_rtl",
    gulp.series("desktop_styles_rtl", function() {
        gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["desktop_styles_rtl"]);
    })
);

gulp.task(
    "watch:desktop_en",
    gulp.series("desktop_styles", function() {
        gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["desktop_styles"]);
    })
);

gulp.task(
    "watch:mobile_rtl",
    gulp.series("mobile_styles_rtl", function() {
        gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["mobile_styles_rtl"]);
    })
);

gulp.task(
    "watch:mobile_en",
    gulp.series("mobile_styles", function() {
        gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["mobile_styles"]);
    })
);

gulp.task(
    "watch:AllMobile",
    gulp.series("mobile_styles", "mobile_styles_rtl", function() {
        gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["mobile_styles"]);
        gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", ["mobile_styles_rtl"]);
    })
);
```

Can someone help me with troubleshooting this? Should I switch to gulp.parallels for the tasks or am I refactoring this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

All of your watches should be of the form:

```
gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", gulp.series(mobile_styles)
```

So, for example, change to:

```
gulp.task(
    "watch:all",
    gulp.series(
        mobile_styles,
        mobile_styles_rtl,
        desktop_styles,
        desktop_styles_rtl,
        function(done) {
            gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", gulp.series(mobile_styles));
            gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", gulp.series(mobile_styles_rtl));
            gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", gulp.series(desktop_styles));
            gulp.watch("./sass/**/*.sass", gulp.series(desktop_styles_rtl));
            done();
        }
    )
);
```

Note that when referring to named functions they are not enclosed in quotes (as a task created with `gulp.task` would be).  And I added the `done` to signal when that task has completed which will be important.

You have to change much of your code to this form.  And your `gulp.task` calls could be converted to named functions as well.  So the beginning of the above code could be:

```
   function watch_all() {
        gulp.series(….
```

[can't use the `:` in a function name though.]

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks a lot for the feedback! I took your comments into consideration and implemented them but I am still getting some errors when I run the gulp tasks. Can you take a look to see if I am missing something?: https://jsfiddle.net/xtao2ype/

Comment: Following up on this, I fixed some syntax issues but I now get task never defined errors when I run "gulp watch_all" for example. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ovLxmu8k/